# How many custom tabs can be created in a salesforce org?

Tags: limits, developer-edition

How many custom tabs can be created in a salesforce org?I don't want these limits for a particular app or managed package,but in an entire org.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below attached screenshot with details

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

```
Personal Contact  Group    Professional  Enterprise  Unlimited  and         Developer
Edition  Manager  Edition  Edition       Edition     Performance Edition    Edition

N/A      3        5        1,210 To      1,210 To    1,210 To exceed,       100
                           exceed,       exceed,     contact
                           contact       contact     Salesforce
                           Salesforce   Salesforce
```

[image]